# Does Windows 10 "data usage overview" include uploads?

Tags: windows-10, bandwidth

Simple question, as per title. Does this thing include uploads? [image: Windows 10 data usage overview]].

And for bonus points, is this the total usage across all network interfaces, or just the currently active one?

Comment: "just the currently active one?" - All traffic on the active adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It shows all data transfer that has taken place over that network adapter (which means all networks over Wi-Fi)